# android image stack on top of each other horizontally

Tags: android, stack, tinder, card

[image]

I want to display an image like this, like in stack on top of each other, How I can achieve this type of design dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this code:-

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/image_1" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/image_2" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/image_3" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-50dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/image_4" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set leftmargin to -16dp for example
or 1/4 of width of your images

Comment: did not understand, is it possible to achieve in recycler view  @Alireza

Comment: let me test on linearLayout